# AWS - Why is my ACM issued cert not appearing when creating a Load Balancer ("No existing certificates")

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to create a Application Load Balancer for a LAMP stack ec2 server.  Both the ec2 server and certificate is deployed in US East(Ohio) us-east-2 and I'm trying create the load balancer there also.

But when I'm setting up the load balancer, and get to the step where I select a ACM managed cert, the dropdown says "No existing certificates".

The certificate is Issued and not In Use.  I created it some time ago (actually, about 2 years ago).  I also tried creating a Classic Load Balancer and the certificate was not available there also.

Comment: Has the certificate expired? Could there be an IAM restriction on your user that prevents it seeing the certificate? Suggest you edit your question to include screenshots of your ACM cert (blank out any details you think necessary) and appropriate ALB page. Also check regions match.

Comment: @Tim Thank You!  The statuses were all green "Success" and "Issued" and no obvious sign that it was somehow expired.  But the "Not after" date was in the past and it said it was ineligible for renewal.  

If you answer the question; I'd be happy to accept your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the the comments above it looks like the certificate has expired. If you want the certificate to renew there are two options:

- DNS CNAME validation (preferred). Create a CNAME for the domain, as instructed by ACM. Leave it there. The certificate will renew automatically.
- Email validation. Every time a renewal is due an email is sent to a variety of emails at the domain of the certificate, for example admin@example.com and some others. Validate the cert by receiving the email and clicking on the link.

For reference, the other things to check are IAM permissions, Service Control Policies, and region.